# Visual studio 2013 documentation comments

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, documentation, comments

Does Visual Studio have something like a typical [java](/questions/tagged/java) IDE to facilitate the entry of [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) documentation comments?

For example, in my Java IDE, when I put the cursor before my function/method and enter `/**` followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the IDE auto-generates a comment template. The comment template includes the arguments for the function/method. I then manually fill in the documentation for each argument.

To further clarify, please consider this function:

```
function int foo (int id);
```

**Procedure:**

1. Place the cursor on the line just before that function.
2. Key-in `/**` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or something like that. (This works in every Java editor I know.)

**Result:**

```
/**
 * @param id
 * @return
 */
```

Answer (score 1):

Triple whack. Put the cursor above a function and type `///`.

A comment stub including the parameters is generated in XML, and can be scraped for compiling documentation.

Comment: I don't wanna xml comments, just normal one like `/**This is my foo function @params id */`

Comment: Are you sure? The neat thing about /// comments is that they are available to Intellisense. That means you get comments popping up when you start typing a function, class, interface, what have you. It comes in handy when disambiguating a bunch of home grown functions.  Also, see the following article for auto documentation. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302121.aspx

Comment: I heard this but you need instal something to Visual Studio to keep it working, it doesn't work natively. (But what should I want from Microsoft ... )

Comment: @RandyCastleberry: The article you reference discusses XML documentation comments for **C#**. Instead see [XML Documentation (Visual C++)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177226.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

How about the [DoxygenComments](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/11a30c1c-593b-4399-a702-f23a56dd8548) extension?

Edit: just saw that it only highlights comments and doesn't create them. [Atomineer Pro](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7912CCF4-60B8-4132-BACE-5ACACEB7233B) does that, but it's not free.

Answer (score 0):

Highlight a block of text and use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to put comments around them. Use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> to uncomment.
You can also try out the [GhostDoc](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/46A20578-F0D5-4B1E-B55D-F001A6345748) visual studio extension.

Comment: You didn't get my question. See Edit notes pls. I don't want to comment block of code i want to "generate" comment for function/class/etc which will include `@params, @return (etc, but its probably all I need)`

Comment: I'm not sure if that's possible in VS natively, but there are plugins that do it. I'm using [Visual Assist](http://www.wholetomato.com/) right now that lets you do pretty much that, it's just a bit difficult to get it up and running.